# Find distance between set and point

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces

Consider the Banach space $X=\left(\mathbb{R}^2, \|\cdot\|_p\right)$ where $p\ge 1$ or $p=\infty$. Let $S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x+y=1\}$. Find the distance $\delta_p$ from $(0,0)$ to the set $S$.

> My solution:

(i) $\delta_p\left((0,0),S\right)=\inf\limits_{(x,y)\in S}\{\|(x,y)\|_p\}=\inf\limits_{(x,y)\in S} \{(x^p+y^p)^{1/p}\}=\inf\limits_{x\in \mathbb{R}} \{\underbrace{(x^p+(1-x)^p)^{1/p}}_\text{h(x)}\}$

Now set $\frac{dh}{dx}=0$ and find $x=\frac12$, so that $y=\frac12$. Take $\frac{d^2h}{dx^2}$ and observe that if $p$ is even then $\frac{d^2h}{dx^2}>0$, and if $p$ is odd then $\frac{d^2h}{dx^2}>0$. How do we deal with this? Is $(x,y)=(\frac12, \frac12)$ the right point, making $\delta_p = \left(2^{1-p}\right)^{1/p}$.

For $p=\infty$ we have

$\delta_\infty\left((0,0), S\right)=\inf\limits_{(x,y)\in S} \{\|x+y\|_\infty\}=\inf\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\{\|x+1-x\|_\infty\}=1$.

Please let me know if you think this approach is correct.

Comment: Might want to explicitly mean the potentiality that $x$ or $y$ is negative, in which case you need absolute value signs

Comment: @eepperly16 We are trying to find whether or not he point $x=\frac12$ is minimum or not. If we take negative values of $x$ then how does that reflect on $x=\frac12$ being minimum?

Comment: Your argument is ultimately that $x=1/2$ is a _local minima_ of $h$. Thus, in order to make your argument that $x = 1/2$ reflects a _global minimum_ of $h$ bullet-proof, you must establish (1) that it is the only local minima and (2) the infimum is obtained. To be rigorous, you must then rule out the case that there exists a local minima of the function for $x < 0$.

Comment: $h$ is minimized iff $h^p$ is minimized. Thus $d^2 h^p/dx^2|_{x = 1/2} = p(p-1) x^{p-2} + p(p-1)(1-x)^{p-2} > 0$ for any $p > 1$, not just $p$ even or odd.

Comment: @eepperly16 Thanks. I must have forgotten first-year calculus.

Comment: Modulo these details, your argument seems good to me, @sequence

Comment: Also you should treat the case $p=1$ differently, as my above argument does not hold for $p=1$. (You have the right answer for $p=1$, but you need to be a little careful about your justification.)

Comment: I think for $p$ the difference is that $\inf \{|x+y|\}=\inf \{|x+1-x|\}=1$.

Comment: It looks like in infinity-norm $\delta=\frac12$.